# Pointer value being lost after function call - C

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int *data;
}Node;


void AllocateNode(Node **newnode)
{
    *newnode = malloc(sizeof(int));
}


void insert(Node **p2head, int *p2data)
{
    if(*p2head == NULL)
    {
        AllocateNode(p2head);
        (**p2head).data = p2data;
    }
}

void ReadAll(Node **headptr)
{
    int x = 10;
    insert(headptr, &x);
}

void traverse(Node *headptr)
{
    printf("%d\n",*(headptr->data));
}

int main(void)
{
    Node *ListHead;
    ListHead = NULL;
    ReadAll(&ListHead);
    printf("%d\n",*(ListHead->data));

    traverse(ListHead);
}
```

I am very confused because

```
printf("%d\n",*(ListHead->data));
```

outputs: 10 - the desired value, however

```
printf("%d\n",*(headptr->data));
```

outputs: 0 - the value is randomly lost after being passed to the traverse function, even though it seems to be assigned correctly after all the other calls.

Comment: `Allocate()` allocates enough storage for an `int`.   However, code which uses that memory expects there to be a `Node` there.   If `sizeof(int) < sizeof (Node)` the behaviour is undefined.   It doesn't help you are storing the address of an automatic variable, and then dereferencing that pointer later (another case of undefined behaviour).

Comment: Are you trying to make a linked list?

Comment: As some answers already pointed out the use-after-free.  You can see it with a live test of your code here:  https://segfault.stensal.com/a/EhGDOQRXG3oGd3Np

Answer (score 1):

An pointer to non-static local variable is passed from `ReadAll()` to `insert()` and it is saved to the newly created node.

This variable becomes unavailable after returning from `ReadAll()` and dereferencing the pointer after that invokes *undefined behavior*. This is the cause of randomness.

To avoid this, the pointer to put on the node should be that points to object that is available even after returning from `ReadAll()`.

This can be archived by dynamically allocating

```
void ReadAll(Node **headptr)
{
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = 10;
    insert(headptr, x);
}
```

or making the variable static.

```
void ReadAll(Node **headptr)
{
    static int x = 10;
    insert(headptr, &x);
}
```

Also, the implementation of `Allocate()` is wrong as Peter pointed out.
The allocation size should be `sizeof(Node)`, not `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Actually `insert` should accept an `int` rather than an `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code :

In

```
void AllocateNode(Node **newnode)
{
    *newnode = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

`*newnode` is a `Node*` so it must be

```
void AllocateNode(Node **newnode)
{
    *newnode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
}
```

In

```
void ReadAll(Node **headptr)
{
    int x = 10;
    insert(headptr, &x);
}
```

you give the address of *x* being a local variable to save it in the Node.

All access through that pointer is invalid and has an unspecified behavior when you exit *ReadAll*

One possibility is to allocate the *int*

```
void ReadAll(Node **headptr)
{
    int * x = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *x = 10;
    insert(headptr, x);
}
```

After these corrections, compilation and execution :

```
vxl15036 /tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra -g l.c
vxl15036 /tmp % ./a.out
10
10
```

Execution under *valgrind*

```
vxl15036 /tmp % valgrind ./a.out
==28709== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28709== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28709== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28709== Command: ./a.out
==28709== 
10
10
==28709== 
==28709== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28709==     in use at exit: 12 bytes in 2 blocks
==28709==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 12 bytes allocated
==28709== 
==28709== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28709==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==28709==    indirectly lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==28709==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28709==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28709==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28709== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==28709== 
==28709== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28709== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: `*newnode` is a `Node*`, so what is pointed at by that is `Node`. Therefore the size should be `sizeof(Node)`, not `sizeof(Node*)`.

Comment: @MikeCAT oh yes, thank you, damned I did two errors when editing the code by hand in the answer rather than to just copy/paste my code ^^